# How to Upload csv using angular and parse data using express API and sent response

Tags: json, angular, csv, express, file-conversion

I m trying to send csv file to express api, M using angular at front-end
Here is the sample code-
app.component.html file

```
<div>
  <h1 style="text-align:center">CSV File Upload</h1>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
      <input type="file" name="csvreport" id="csvreport" (change)="fileupload($event.target.files)">
  </form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts file

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from "@angular/common/http";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fileupload(files: FileList) {
    let file: File = files.item(0);
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append("file", file, file.name);
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/chartreportx/us-central1/chartreportapi/reportfile', formData)
    .subscribe(data=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(data))}, err=>{console.log(err)});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(file.name));
  }
}
```

I suspect that the issue is with api, I have tried multiple methods to get the formdata parse in the right way but all gives null result, Finally I got array buffer as output, but still array buffer is not valid

Express API:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as csvtojson from 'csvtojson';
import * as file_upload from 'express-fileupload';


const app = express();
app.use(file_upload())
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
  })
);
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  next();
});

app.get('/',(req, res) =>{
    res.status(200).json({chartreportapi:'works'});
})


app.post('/reportfile', (req, res)=>{
    let csvDataBuffer = JSON.stringify(req.body);
    let csvData = JSON.parse(csvDataBuffer).data;
    let csvDataString = csvData.toString('utf8')
    console.log(csvData.toString('utf8'));
    return csvtojson().fromString(csvDataString).then(json => {return res.status(201).json({csv:csvDataString, json:json})})

})

exports.chartreportapi = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Output which i m getting with this API is as follows, but is not the desired result:

```
{"csv":"45,45,45,45,45,45,87,....","json":[]}
```

Have also checked many SO questions for this issue, but not found any proper solution, 
Please let me know what is going wrong, also any further detail is required on this

Comment: Here's an article that might help you out when processing your CSV: https://www.techighness.com/post/node-expressjs-endpoint-to-upload-and-process-csv-file/

Comment: @Brandom the article speaks about using more packages like multer, fast-csv, is it necessary to use this package, when i upload files using normal html, api works, but it creates issue when i try to use it in angular

Comment: No, they're not, but they can certainly make things more convenient. Uploading multi-part data from Angular is sometimes finicky.

Comment: I will try them in little time, but can you help me in understanding what is getting wrong with above code

Comment: Seems like you're trying to parse the entire request body as the CSV file instead of the CSV file itself would be my guess.

Comment: when `console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body))` it has given json output `{type:buffer, data:["45,45,45,"]}`, so I have parse request body

Comment: What are you expecting to send back as your response?

Comment: file that i m uploading has tables, the output should be like this `"json": [
        {
            "Product_ID": "500001",
            "Product_Name": "Benzylpenicillin",
            "Product_Category": "Anti-Bacterial",
            "Unit_Of_Measure": "EA"
        },]`

Comment: Ah. You'll have to parse the data in the CSV and return it in the shape you need. That's where a CSV parsing library might be able to save you some work.

Comment: I have created similar api for html form post, over there it works smoothly, it is creating issue here [similar api link](https://github.com/Vino16491/csv2json/blob/master/server.js) [api demo](https://csvjsonapi.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Hard to say what's wrong unless I dug into it myself, which is a bit more than I want to start doing; it's close to midnight where I am in the world :)

Comment: yes its true, I woke up whole night to find the issue, thanks :)

Comment: I've been there many, many times. Sometimes it's best to just step away for a while and come back it with a fresh set of eyes.

Comment: seems you are correct, i will leave it for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't got the exact issue, but what i found sending raw file data using angular is bit noisy, so I have converted the data to string before sending it to API-

> Method Updated in app.component.ts file

```
fileupload(files: FileList) {
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      let file: File = files.item(0);
      let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsText(file);
      fileReader.onload = ev => {
        let csvdata = fileReader.result.toString();
        let body = {data:csvdata};
        return this.http.post('apiurl',body)
         .subscribe((data:any)=>console.log(JSON.stringify(data.json)));
      };
    }
  }
```

Now I m getting data in string format, so it is now easy to convert string into json

> API method updated-

```
 app.post('/reportfile', (req, res)=>{
      let csvDataBuffer = JSON.stringify(req.body);
      let csvData = JSON.parse(csvDataBuffer).data;
      let csvDataString = csvData.toString("utf8");
        return csvtojson()
         .fromString(csvDataString)
         .then(json => {
           return res.status(201).json({csv:csvDataString, json:json})
          })
     })
```

In this way i was able to convert the csv file to json data using API, 
the same csv file can also be converted to json at client side, but requirement was to do at API